# How to do update time every 90 minutes

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I made some tree structure coding in java. 
I have tried...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] K = new int[3][16];
    int c=1;
    int index=0;
    System.out.println("Levels:");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    index = reader.nextInt();

    for(int x=0;x<=index;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<c;y++)
        {
            K[x][y]=y;



//             System.out.println("K["+x+"]["+y+"]="+y);

        }
        c=c*4;
    }
    System.out.println("Node index:");
    int node = reader.nextInt();
    int temp;
    reader.close();

    for(int t=index - 1; t >= 0; t -- )
    {
        temp=node/4;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++) {
            if(temp * 4 + j == node) {

                System.out.println("{K\'[" + t + "][" + temp + "]}_K\'[" + (t+1) + "][" + (temp * 4 + j) + "] || ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("{K\'[" + t + "][" + temp + "]}_K[" + (t+1) + "][" + (temp * 4 + j) + "] || ");
            }
        }
        node /= 4;
}

}
}
```

I have a problem. how to do define time in java. In my research i want to make key tree nodes are update given time and their parent nodes are should be update.

example:

```
nodes [2][0] - 00:00 ~ 1.30 
      [2][1]- 1:30 ~ 3:00
```

nodes are update every 90 minutes and if [2][1] updated, other sibling and parent should be update. **Key tree** shown in figure

How I can solve this problem ....?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to use a ScheduledExecutorService https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html